# Dynamically renaming of column names with column values present in some other table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to solve a problem where I have 2 tables in Oracle:
Table 1

```
id  name
101 xyz
102 abc
103 def
```

Table 2

```
columnname columndesc
id   identifier
name customer name
```

I want to rename the column name of Table1 with the values present in Table2

Expected output is:

```
identifier customer name
101 xyz
102 abc
103 def
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is you should use a Cursor to iterate through each row of `Table1` and for each of these rows execute the alter table.

Another option is to also use a cursor to iterate through `Table` rows and instead build one `Alter Table` statement, which in turn can be run with  `EXEC`

Useful links:

- [Alter Table](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php)
- [List item](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php)
- [Execute command](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm)

Comment: Thanks Szymon for your response, is it possible to share some sample code !

Answer (score 0):

For such dynamic renaming you have to use `execute immediate` to achieve it,

Here is the sample code using a normal `for loop`,

```
begin
  for i in (select columnname,columndesc from table2) loop
    begin
       execute immediate 'alter table table1 rename column '||i.columnname ||' to '||i.columndesc;
    exception
       when others then
         dbms_output.put_line('Renaming failed for column '''|| i.columnname ||''' and columndesc '''||i.columndesc||'''');
         continue;
    end;
  end loop; 
end;
/
```

The code is self explanatory, however I have listed some points to be taken care which are instantly coming to mind.

1. I hope the the `table1's` columns you are trying to rename are exactly same as value of `columnname` in `table2`
2. During the rename as you see I have put the statements in `begin end` and using `exception` we just skip the one which will fail.
3. Failure reason could be anything such as,
   . the column name you are trying to rename doesn't exists
   . the column name value from `columndesc` exceeds 30/128 char (version < oracle 12.2 and version > oracle 12.2 its 128 characters ) which is the limit in oracle for object names
4. I have hard coded the table `table1` as only talble to rename in this example but again you have got idea now where you can even make the table as dynamic also if you want.

*At the end bottom line is to use `execute immediate` for your primary purpose but you also need to consider all the `failure` cases as the compilation and execution of the actual statements will happen during run time.*

EDIT:

Do not use space in columndesc in `table2` as `customr name` rather use `-` like `customer_name` which is standard naming for oracle.

Comment: `exceeds 30 char is the limit in Oracle for object names` . That was true only until version 12.2. Starting with Oracle 12.2 , you can have columns and tables up to 128 characters.

Comment: That was indeed a good hint. Thank you @Roberto Hernandez

Comment: Thanks , it was very useful !

Comment: @MalikaDewan Did the answer resolve your issue ? if yes please accept and give a tick mark. Thank you.